# Comparison logic on Value and it's Prototype

Tags: javascript, logic

So, there is a "*problem*":
You have

```
let kind_1_ = "some_string"
let kind_2_ = 1234
let kind_3_ = [ "can be string or...", 0, { "some_prop" : "any possible type of value" }, ["...or this"] ]
let kind_4_ = { "even_this" : "will be appropriate" }

const prototype = [ "string", 0, [], {} ]
/* as well as   = [ "string", 0, [] ]       */
/* or as        = [ 0, {} ]                 */
/* and so on... but in most cases with this
   | 4 particular types                     */
```

So, we have to compare **kind**s to the **prototype**. There is only **1 kind** and **1 prototype** given at the time. My code for this was as simple as this:

```
let this_will_be_called = (kind, proto) => {
    let bool_to_return = false
    for (let each in proto)
    {
        if (typeof(kind) == typeof(proto)) {
            bool_to_return = true
            return bool_to_return
        }
    }
    return bool_to_return
}

this_will_be_called(kind_any_of_kinds, prototype)
```

Of course, it's not working the way it should. One *Major* problem is that you can't effectively compare [] to {}, because they are both of type **Object** (*I know about Array.isArray()*). But in case of the following situations, it must return **false**:

```
let kind = []
var prototype = [.., {}] /* without [] in here */

/* or this */
let kind = {}
var prototype = [.., []] /* without {} in here */

/* but must return true if: */
let kind = {} /* or let kind = [] */
var prototype = [.., [], {}]
```

And in the end, it must return **false** if no types matching.
My logic is explained in this *pseudo-code*:

```
FOR every element in prototype:
    IF (type of element == type of kind) and (element is NOT Array):
        return TRUE
    ELSE IF (type of element == type of kind) and (element is Array):
        IF (type of kind is NOT an Object) and (kind is Array):
            return TRUE
        ELSE IF (type of kind is an Object):
            return FALSE
    ELSE IF (type of element == type of kind) and (element is Object) and (element is NOT an Array):
        IF (kind is NOT an Array):
            return TRUE
        ELSE IF (kind is an Array):
            return FALSE
    ELSE:
        return FALSE
```

Now, I need your attention to **audit** my logic, because I've completely broke my brain on solving this. Even if above logic works, it's not an elegant solution. So, you could modify it for better performance.

My appreciation on **every** solution! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first, your `prototype` is an array, so when you do `for..in` you get an index of the array, not the item, so you'll need add something like `each = proto[each];`

Than, when it comes to detect array vs object, you can detect if `kind` or `each` an array compare them and return if the same, if none is an array, proceed as before with `typeof`.

```js
let this_will_be_called = (kind, proto) => {
    let bool_to_return = false
    for (let each in proto)
    {
        each = proto[each];

        const isKindArray = Array.isArray(kind),
              isEachArray = Array.isArray(each);

        if (isKindArray || isEachArray)
        {
          if (isKindArray && isEachArray)
            return true;
        }
        else if (typeof(kind) == typeof(each)) {
            bool_to_return = true
            return bool_to_return
        }
    }
    return bool_to_return
}

let kind = []
let prototype = [ "string", 0, {} ] /* without [] in here */
console.log(this_will_be_called(kind, prototype), "kind", kind, "proto", prototype)

/* or this */
kind = {}
prototype = [ "string", 0, [] ] /* without {} in here */
console.log(this_will_be_called(kind, prototype), "kind", kind, "proto", prototype)

/* but must return true if: */
kind = {} /* or let kind = [] */
prototype = [ "string", 0, [], {} ]
console.log(this_will_be_called(kind, prototype), "kind", kind, "proto", prototype)


/* as well as   = [ "string", 0, [] ]       */
/* or as        = [ 0, {} ]                 */
/* and so on... but in most cases with this
   | 4 particular types                     */

kind= "some_string"
console.log(this_will_be_called(kind, prototype), "kind", kind, "proto", prototype)

kind = 1234
console.log(this_will_be_called(kind, prototype), "kind", kind, "proto", prototype)

kind = [ "can be string or...", 0, { "some_prop" : "any possible type of value" }, ["...or this"] ]
console.log(this_will_be_called(kind, prototype), "kind", kind, "proto", prototype)

kind = { "even_this" : "will be appropriate" }
console.log(this_will_be_called(kind, prototype), "kind", kind, "proto", prototype)
```

Comment: @vanomw Oh my god, that was THAT simple xD Thank you much, bro))

Comment: @vanomw Yeeah, I knew about proto[each], just mistyped at the first place)